# C++ dynamic binding problem

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, g++

The questions are:
a) Is the following code legal or not ? (considering it crashes at run-time)
b) If there is any compiler flag for gcc or MVC to show at compile time, a potential problem in the following code ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A
{
public:
    void write(){   cout<<"A"; }    
};
class B
{
public:
    virtual void write(){ cout<<"B"; }  
};
int main()
{

    A *pa=(A*) new B();
    pa->write();
    B *pb=(B*) new A() ;
    pb->write();

    delete pa;
    delete pb;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you are c-style casting, try c++ casting operators

Comment: @baris: It's not *implict* casting!

Comment: any specific reason for casting `new B()` to `A*`? they are not all related to one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not legal.  `B` doesn't derive from `A`, nor vice versa.  Forcing a cast like this results in undefined behaviour.  You're telling the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing", which leads to all sorts of trouble.  This is one reason to avoid old C-style casts, and use C++-style casts instead (`static_cast`, etc.).

Comment: But one can still shoot themselves on the foot using `reinterpret_cast` though.

Comment: @Naveen: Yes.  However, `reinterpret_cast` has been designed as a sort of "red-flag" for your source code.  It's very easy to find them in a code review!